# Error al intentar conectar Yii2 con SQLite

Tags: php, sqlite, yii2

Estoy tratando de conectar mi aplicación en Yii2 con una base de datos en SQLite pero cada vez que intento entrar a mi aplicación me sale el siguiente error: The configuration for the "db" component must contain a "class" element.

Así tengo mi conexión a la base de datos en SQLite

`return [
'components' => [

        'db' => [
            'class' => 'yii\db\Connection',
            'dsn' => 'sqlite:/softwareoperacional.db',
        ],

    ],
];`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seguido al **sqlite:** debes indicar la ruta y el nombre de la base de datos  sqlite, de esta forma:

Ubique la **base de datos** (**dbsqlite.d**b) dentro de mi proyecto, en la carpeta **web\sqlitedb**.

**db.php**

```
return [
    'class' => 'yii\db\Connection',
    'dsn' => 'sqlite:C:\xampp\htdocs\YII2_basic\web\sqlitedb\dbsqlite.db',
   ];
```

o especificando de esta forma:

```
 'dsn' => 'sqlite:@webroot/sqlitedb/dbsqlite.db',
```